# Send a line to opened CMD window

Tags: python, windows, command-line, bcrypt

I got a list of paroles in a .txt file, one of them is a key for `bcrypt`ed file. The problem is, that you can't just type

```
bcrypt.exe somefile.bfe anotherfile.se key
```

The output looks like this

```
bcrypt.exe somefiile.bfe anotherfile.se
Encryption key:
```

BTW it should be decryption key, but doesn't matter.

I can find this CMD window by WINAPI but i don't know how to pass a string to it.

Comment: have you tried [SendKeys](http://code.google.com/p/sendkeys-ctypes/) module?

Comment: haven't yet. thanks, i'll try it out.